# NSJSONSerialization from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsjsonserialization

Is it possible if I have a NSString and I want to use NSJSONSerialization? How do I do this?

Comment: There is a good tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5 concerning the use of NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: In case performance is your priority, JSONKit is a better alternative.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

First you will need to convert your `NSString` to `NSData` by doing the following

```
NSData *data = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then simply use the `JSONObjectWithData` method to convert it to JSON

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: for convenience, you can put this code into NSJSONSerialization Category.

Comment: Use 'NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData' carefully, as, although it has an NSError* parameter, it might throw an exceptions when an error occurs! It is recommendable to enclose it with an '@try {} @catch(...)' block.

Answer (score 13):

You need to convert your `NSString` to `NSData`, at that point you can use the `+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:]` method.

```
NSString * jsonString = YOUR_STRING;
NSData * data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError * error = nil;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (!json) {
    // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your string to NSData by saying:

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can then use it with `NSJSONSerialization`. Note however that `NSJSONSerialization` is iOS5 only, so you might be better off using a library like TouchJSON or JSONKit, both of which let you work directly with strings anyway, saving you the step of converting to NSData.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post that demonstrates how to wrap the native iOS JSON class in a general protocol together with an implementation that use the native iOS JSON class.

This approach makes it a lot easier to use the native functionality and reduces the amount of code you have to write. Furthermore, it makes it a lot easier to switch out the native implementation with, say, JSONKit, if the native one would prove to be insufficient.

http://danielsaidi.com/blog/2012/07/04/json-in-ios

The blog post contains all the code you need. Just copy / paste :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please note that the post is 5 years old :)