# understand JSON parse to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSJSONSerialization from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858814/nsjsonserialization-from-nsstring)

I have this old code, how do I accomplish using `NSJSONSerialization`?

Below uses `SBJSON`

```
+ (NSDictionary *) parseJSONResponse: (NSString *) response {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [response JSONValue];
    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: If you **know** that you can use `NSJSONSerialization`, why don't you google its class reference?

Comment: Or google "NSJSONSerialization example". Or "NSJSONSerialization tutorial". Whenever you have questions about a class (a) look at the Apple docs; and failing that, (b) look for examples and/or tutorials.

Comment: I did and it wasnt clear, so i asked the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the response NSData to perform the following:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```