# Serialize NSString as JSON String

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a `NSString *str = @"abcd"`, and I want to serialize it as JSON String which becomes 
`"abcd"`.
How should I do?

I have tried this
[NSJSONSerialization from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858814/nsjsonserialization-from-nsstring?answertab=active#tab-top), but it doesn't work. The returned `id` is `0x0`.

This is my tricky code what I am using now to do this

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"result": str};
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
body = [body substringFromIndex:14];
body = [body substringToIndex:body.length - 2];
```

Finally
I read spec about JSON and know that OC follows old JSON spec that just thinks object and array is valid. That's the reason why `NSJSONSerialization` cannot serialize JSON string.

Comment: Define "doesn't work."

Comment: Read the error. It's not a really valid "JSON" (well except it you use .allowFragments in the decoding). In fact, if you just want to pass it, just do `NSData *jsonData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`?

Comment: Please add more code.

Comment: I have no more code, I just want to find a method to serialize OC string as json string. JSON contains six types within String, why this string is not a valid string for JSON?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. A single JSON string is just a string so you can write `NSString *body = str;`

Comment: Your code on json serialization is correct. I think the issue is the substringFromIndex: is problematic. Try to comment out the 2 last lines and NSLog on body after initWithData.

Comment: Do you really just want to JSON-encode a string, so that special characters are escaped and so forth?

Comment: @vadian Nonono, a JSON String is useful to do data exchange cross different language.

Comment: @GeneCode `options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` adds extra space chars, so I must remove them by `substring`. That is not the focus point.

Comment: @Caleb Yeah! I just want to JSON-encode a string. The way I using now is not a simple direct method. It is a trick.

Comment: The result of your code is exactly the same as `NSString *body = str`. It's unclear what you are going to accomplish. Anyway it's pretty pointless to create a dictionary, convert it to JSON and extract the dictionary value with string manipulation. There is no difference between a plain string  and the JSON representation of a plain string.

Comment: @vadian If a string literal is `abcd`,then its JSON-encoded is `"abcd"`. If a string literal is `"abcd"`, then its JSON-encoded is `"\"abcd\""`. And, you should distinguish string as NSString in OC runtime and as JSON for data exchange in network. They don't equal.

Comment: OK, then just add the double quotes and write `NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", str];`

Comment: @vadian I just want a common api to do this, not constructing it by myself. It is so strange I cannot find it, it should be a standard api.

Comment: @zhuisui That's a special case for JSON. "Quite new". iOS allows it in the decoding using `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`, but there is no option in writing, since I guess it's just easily done with doing as said by vadian.

Comment: @LarmeThanks, but what I need is not read. Adding double quote around string is not enough, you must handle escape. I know a third-party JSON lib which supports serializing JSON string, so maybe can use it.